# My Python program reports "list index out of range"

Tags: if-statement

Problem:

> Enter 10 integers and create a program that outputs the number of multiples of 3 and the number of multiples of 5 respectively.

ex)input:
10 15 36 99 100 19 46 88 87 13

ex)print:
Multiples of 3 : 4
Multiples of 5 : 3

my code:

```
t=0
f=0
a=list(input().split())
for i in range(11):
    if int(a[i])%3==0: #index
        t+=1
    else:
        int(a[i]) % 5==0
        f += 1
    print('Multiples of 3 :',t)
    print('Multiples of 5 :',f)
```

Error:

```
if int(a[i])%3==0:
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

What's wrong?

Comment: What about range , you stated it is 10 element array shouldnt it be range 10 in this case ?

Comment: I think...This code is perfect so I don't know What's wrong/......

Comment: It is range 11 in your code snippet !! That will give you out of index exception because your array has only 10 elements , array[11] will throw error

Comment: ummmmm.......I change 11-> 10 but still error what's wrong?

Comment: can you mark my answer correct if it helps !

Answer (score 1):

Try this python code snippet

```
t=0
f=0
n = int(input("Enter number of elements : "))
for i in range(0, n):
ele = int(input())
if (ele % 3) == 0:
  t = t + 1
elif (ele % 5) == 0:
  f = f + 1  
else: 
 print("element not counted")
print('Multiples of 3 :',t)
print('Multiples of 5 :',f)
```

I tried this code for list of 3 values of 3, 5 and 10 respectively

[image: Running code snippet]

Comment: This looks like a helpful answer, but samples of console output might be best rendered as text, not as images of text. The latter will present issues to clipboards, search-engine robots, and screen-readers.